# How can my java app detect if its being blocked by firewall

Tags: java, windows, sockets, networking

I have created an application for desktop using JAVA which works like a server and accepts incoming connections using `ServerSocket` . The software works over LAN and needs to be allowed by firewall. How can I check from within the app if its being blocked by the PC's firewall ?

Comment: If opening a socket fails, you can guess.... otherwise if it works, there's no firewall problems.... ;-)

Comment: There is no reliable way to determine that a failed connection was caused by a blocking firewall.

Comment: Why write a program, why not just ask your system administrator or network administrator if you have been blocked ? Pick up the phone.

Comment: @Siddharth the software will be installed by users on their home pc. I am just trying to help them identify the problem, if the software doesn't work for them.

Comment: Think about it, you are trying to write a software to identify a problem in another software from the outside. All answers on this question are wrong, since there is not answer to your question. You have your basics mixed up about programming.

Comment: @Siddharth the diagnostic will be a part of the main software. It will not distributed as a separate utility. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nope, you are not making any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to connect to a reliable site eg stackoverflow.com with

```
   try {
        new Socket("stackoverflow.com", 80);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // something is wrong, not necessarily firewall problem
        ... 
    }

    // no firewall
```

Comment: Didn't realise the solution would be so simple. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you catch the exception while creating the server socket then you can safely that port is not available for listening, here is code sample:

```
try {
        socket = new ServerSocket(_port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Port in use");
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but that doesn't prove there is a firewall in the way, and printing 'poet in use' when you can't connect to it is just plain wrong. -1